# SQL(ite) Remove (and keep some) duplicates in table

Tags: sql, sqlite, join

Say I have a table, called `tablex`, as follows:

```
name|year
---------
Bob | 2010
Mary| 2011
Sam | 2012
Mary| 2012
Bob | 2013
```

Names appear at most twice. I want to remove from the table only those names that are repeated and have a difference of one year (in which case I want to keep the newer year).

```
name|year
---------
Bob | 2010
Sam | 2012
Mary| 2012
Bob | 2013
```

I have tried:

```
SELECT a.Name, a.Year, b.Year
FROM tablex AS a
LEFT JOIN tablex AS b
ON a.Name=b.Name AND (a.Year=b.Year OR b.Year-a.Year=1)
ORDER BY a.Name, a.Year
```

results in:

```
  Name YearA YearB
1  Bob  2010  2010
2  Bob  2013  2013
3 Mary  2011  2011
4 Mary  2011  2012
5 Mary  2012  2012
6  Sam  2012  2012
```

Bob's and Sam's entries are correct, how can I restrict it further to only include `Mary 2012 2012`?

Comment: From the question is not clear if you want to `SELECT` (suppressing the duplicates) or actually `DELETE` the "duplicates".

Comment: It is `SELECT` that I wanted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the question is not clear if you want to SELECT (suppressing the duplicates) or actually DELETE the "duplicates". The select case:

```
SELECT a.Name, a.Year
FROM tablex AS a
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT * FROM tablex AS b
    WHERE b.Name = a.Name
    AND b.Year = a.Year +1
   );
```

And the delete case:

```
DELETE
FROM tablex AS a
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT * FROM tablex AS b
    WHERE b.Name = a.Name
    AND b.Year = a.Year +1
   );
```

Comment: LOL, some idiot downvoted this answer cause of something unrelated. Care to discuss it?

Answer (score 0):

This operation deletes rows from the table where the same name with a newer year also exist:

```
delete from tablex t1 where year < (select max(year) from tablex where name = t1.name)
```

Comment: Deletes rows from the table where the same name with a newer year also exist.

Answer (score 0):

```
DELETE FROM tablex t
WHERE year + 1 =
  (SELECT MAX(year)
   FROM tablex
   WHERE name = t.name)
```

Or, if you don't want to delete anything, but want a query to only give the desired results:

```
SELECT *
FROM tablex t
WHERE year + 1 !=
  (SELECT MAX(year)
   FROM tablex
   WHERE name = t.name)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use :

```
SELECT a.Name, a.Year, b.Year
FROM tablex AS a
LEFT JOIN tablex AS b
ON a.Name=b.Name AND (a.Year=b.Year )
ORDER BY a.Name, a.Year
```